# SSIS vs VBA Excel file parsing

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, sql-server-2012, vba

I am looking for alternatives to parse a file. 
The application I am developing is based on Excel VBA and uses a SQL server 2012 data base to save data.
One of the feature  of the application consist in parsing a file.
For now the file is parsed by some VBA code and the results are stored into the data base. 
The process is slow and require many requests to the data base. I cannot pool the requests into a bigger one because this is not supported by the SQL server version I use (2012). Also I do not want to script SQL code on the Excel client side (all SQL code is saved into stored procedure trigger from the VBA code).

My question is : do you think it is possible to parse a file using SSIS the process being driven from VBA code ?
How SSIS powerfull can be to parse data. The file to parse is a product BOM (list of parts containing other parts) which look like the following (the real ones have around 1000 lines)

```
Level   Number      Revision    Quantity    Description
0       Master BOM  00          1           part:Master BOM-revision:00-criticity:-desc:OP ADMIN BOM TO MANAGE VISION PROJECT
1       BOM X       12          1           part:BOM X-revision:12-criticity-desc:OPERATIONS COUNTER
2       A           05          1           part:A-revision:05-criticity:MEDIUM/MAJOR-desc:COUNTER
3       B           08          3           part:B-revision:08-criticity:MEDIUM/MAJOR-desc:FEMALE CONTACT
2       C           07          1           part:C-revision:07-criticity:-desc:SWITCH - SAIA X3M312N2KAJ32
3       D           00          1           part:D-revision:00-criticity:-desc:SCREW MSC SL Z XREC M3 X 8 STL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this question is in line with the SO guidelines as it may attract opinions. Yet, just putting out my response in case it helps.

SSIS alone can be a solution here. You can set the source as File type, perform transformations using plenty of built in features and then use the database as a sink.

There are alternate options as well which can be used based on how the data is in the Excel file.

1. SQL server import export wizard
2. OpenRowset
3. Linked server set up where Excel will act as one server.

While this may not be the *answer* to the question, I feel it is too big to fit in the comment with proper formatting.

Comment: the wizard won't do it I want to automate the process as much as possible. The application users are basic users. Thx